# Behringer usb Guitar Link, how to?

Tags: 12.04, sound, usb

I have a usb guitar link as stated in the title, and cannot get the thing to work with Ubuntu. The device is connected and running but I get no sound through the guitar.
[image]
I know it uses a AISO driver for windows if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution http://akshathabel.blogspot.in/2013/04/electric-guitars-on-ubuntu-1304.html. Hope this helps.